# Extension project templates not appearing in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, ios-app-extension

I'm not sure if I am the only one experiencing this program, but I have tried searching and have not been able to find anyone in my current situation. I downloaded Xcode 6 beta and was interested in Extension programming for iOS 8. However, I have been unable to locate the extensions in my project templates when creating a new project in Xcode, I saw a YouTube video (unrelated to extension programming) but I did notice that the option was not there for the said video. Now, I have had a look through the contents of the Xcode 6 beta package and have been able to locate the actual templates themselves, so I have no doubt they are present, it just seems that they are not actually being loaded.

For the record, I also downloaded some example custom keyboard code from GitHub in order to see whether Xcode will recognise it and it does, going as far as actually displaying the 'E' icon beside the build target. I should also mention that I do have a build of Xcode 5 also present on my machine.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue, or does anyone know how to overcome it?

Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You create a extension by creating a new target in an existing project.

[image]

Check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW1) for more information

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot. I can't believe I missed, that. It didn't even cross my mind that the keyboard had have an icon associated with it, and that meant creating an application.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. The solution was to not try to add the extension in `File/new/File...` menu but in `File/new/Target...` menu.

You can add extension to any existing project.