# custom keyboard app extension not appearing in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

So, I've been researching the realm of custom keyboards and I was about to get started. Then, once I opened Xcode, I naturally looked for the "Custom Keyboard" template under "Application Extension". This template option can be seen in a screen shot in a custom keyboard tutorial by WeLoveSwift (https://www.weheartswift.com/make-custom-keyboard-ios-8-using-swift/). I realize that a question like this (if not exactly) has been asked ([Extension project templates not appearing in Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056290/extension-project-templates-not-appearing-in-xcode-6)) here. Sadly, I don't really understand the answer/it doesn't help.

Thanks very much and thanks a load in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I feel stupid: There is literally a button at the top left. This button has the app's name on it, and an up arrow and a down arrow on top of each other on its right. You click on it and then you click on "Add Target". This opens up the page that I was looking for.